# Decode RTP iLBC payload

Tags: audio, rtp, codec

I want to decode [iLBC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3952) audio data from RTP payload using c++? I can extract payload data but I don't know how to decode an iLBC frame. How to do that? Is there any reliable library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To decode iLBC frames, I use from [this](https://github.com/TimothyGu/libilbc) library. At first I thought it was not a reliable library but now I have no problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can also explore pjmedia ilbc codec.

https://www.pjsip.org/pjmedia/docs/html/group__PJMED__ILBC.htm#details

https://github.com/jfigus/PJSIP/blob/master/pjproject-2.1.0/pjmedia/src/pjmedia-codec/ilbc.c